# Natural language rendering

Tags: frameworks, artificial-intelligence, nlp

Do you know any frameworks that implement natural language rendering concept ?
I've found several NLP oriented frameworks like [Anthelope](http://www.proxem.com/Antelope/WhatisAntelope/tabid/67/Default.aspx) or [Open NLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/) but they have only parsers but not renderers or builders. For example I want to render a question about smth. I'm constructing sentence object, setting it's properties, specify it's language and then render as a plain text. 
Please advice. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a plain text renderer as simple as "concatenate all the sentence structures in order" (pseudocode, I know)? Something like a tree traversal + `StringBuilder` or the non-.NET equivalent of it? So couldn't you write one based on the sentence object definition you are obviously already using? And wouldn't the large complexity difference be a reason that NLP oriented frameworks only seem to do parsing?

(Please feel free to tell me off for not getting the question if you think this is approriate...)

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Well, tree traversal helps a lot if you have such a tree, but what if you don't ? So, if i'm starting from a very high level of abstraction (meaning) and constructing sentence from scratch dynamically depending from situation ? Of course i need some language templates for questions, answers, emotional characteristics and so on. Also such templeates can vary from language to language. In this context the purpose of language rendering framework is providing such mechanisms and templates. Does this make sense ?